# Unresolvable SVN tree conflict

Tags: svn

I created the name of a Java package in my project and now I'm getting a lot of Tree Conflicts. Even if I mark them as "working", it doesn't let me commit the changes.

```
$ svn commit CaramhellActivity.java 

Log message unchanged or not specified
(a)bort, (c)ontinue, (e)dit:
c
Adding         CaramhellActivity.java
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: File '/candy-wars/trunk/CandyWars/src/com/rifsoft/android/caramhell/CaramhellActivity.java' already exists
 svn resolve --accept 'working' CaramhellActivity.java 
$ svn commit CaramhellActivity.java 
Log message unchanged or not specified
(a)bort, (c)ontinue, (e)dit:
c
Adding         CaramhellActivity.java
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: File '/candy-wars/trunk/CandyWars/src/com/rifsoft/android/caramhell/CaramhellActivity.java' already exists
$ svn update CaramhellActivity.java    C CaramhellActivity.java
At revision 60.
Summary of conflicts:
  Tree conflicts: 1
$ svn resolve --accept 'working' CaramhellActivity.java 
Resolved conflicted state of 'CaramhellActivity.java'
$ svn commit CaramhellActivity.java 
Log message unchanged or not specified
(a)bort, (c)ontinue, (e)dit:
c
Adding         CaramhellActivity.java
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: File '/candy-wars/trunk/CandyWars/src/com/rifsoft/android/caramhell/CaramhellActivity.java' already exist
```

I'm using Linux, svn, version 1.6.6 (r40053).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This maybe an obvious suggestion, but did you already run a clean up on that directory?

`svn cleanup`

If that doesn't work, this post discusses how to recover from a different error by deleting the log files and some other stuff - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158664/what-to-do-when-svn-cleanup-fails

Comment: Yes, the cleanup did nothing. Gonna check that link.

Comment: Most voted from that link worked fine. Also I diretcly used svn from console to do all the stuff, and not the **AWFUL** tool included in Eclipse Indigo.